# Substring between lines using Regular Expression Java

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

Hi I am having following string

```
abc test ...
interface
somedata ...
xxx ...
!
sdfff as ##
example
yyy sdd @# .
!
```

I have a requirement that I want to find content between a line having word "interface" or "example" and a line "!".
Required output will be something like below

```
String[] output= {"somedata ...\nxxx ...\n","yyy sdd @# .\n"} ;
```

I can do this manually using substring and iteration . But I want to achieve this using regular expression.
Is it possible?

This is what I have tried

```
String sample="abc\ninterface\nsomedata\nxxx\n!\nsdfff\ninterface\nyyy\n!\n";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?m)\ninterface(.*?)\n!\n");
    Matcher m =pattern.matcher(sample);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

Am I Right? Please suggest a right way of doing it .

Edit :

A small change : I want to find content between a line "interface" or "example" and a line "!".

Can we achieve this too using regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `(?s)` DOTALL modifier.

```
String sample="abc\ninterface\nsomedata\nxxx\n!\nsdfff\ninterface\nyyy\n!\n";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<=\\ninterface\\n).*?(?=\\n!\\n)");//Pattern.compile("(?m)^.*$");
Matcher m =pattern.matcher(sample);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
somedata
xxx
yyy
```

Note that the input in your example is different.

- `(?<=\\ninterface\\n)` Asserts that the match must be preceded by the characters which are matched by the pattern present inside the positive lookbehind.
- `(?=\\n!\\n)` Asserts that the match must be followed by the characters which are matched by the pattern present inside the positive lookahead.

**Update:**

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?<=\\n(?:example|interface)\\n).*?(?=\\n!\\n)");
```

Comment: Yes its working . Thanks . Pls see at edited question . can u help me for that ?

Comment: What do you mean by someother text? Just put an OR operator inside the lookbehind like `(?<=\\ninterface\\n|someother text)`